# Incorrect Syntax Error running SQL command in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlconnection

I have a SQL command that I'm running in VB.NET... I've written this type of command countless times, however, I'm getting an error when trying to process the command below:

```
Dim VIconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MBSRVERP01;Initial Catalog=MBUk;Integrated Security=True") 
Dim CMDoperation As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
CMDoperation.Connection = VIconn
CMDoperation.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO PRJCREATION.dbo.OPERATION_CO (WORKORDER_TYPE, WORKORDER_BASE_ID, WORKORDER_LOT_ID, WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, WORKORDER_SUB_ID, SEQUENCE_NO, RESOURCE_ID, SETUP_HRS, " _
                                & "RUN, RUN_TYPE, LOAD_SIZE_QTY, RUN_HRS, MOVE_HRS, TRANSIT_DAYS, SERVICE_ID, SCRAP_YIELD_PCT, SCRAP_YIELD_TYPE, FIXED_SCRAP_UNITS, MINIMUM_MOVE_QTY, CALC_START_QTY, " _
                                & "CALC_END_QTY, COMPLETED_QTY, DEVIATED_QTY, ACT_SETUP_HRS, ACT_RUN_HRS, STATUS, SETUP_COMPLETED, SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE, OPERATION_TYPE, DRAWING_ID, DRAWING_REV_NO, " _
                                & "OVERRIDE_QTYS, BEGIN_TRACEABILITY, CAPACITY_USAGE_MAX, CAPACITY_USAGE_MIN, TEST_ID, SPC_QTY, SCHED_START_DATE, SCHED_FINISH_DATE, COULD_FINISH_DATE, ISDETERMINANT, " _
                                & "SETUP_COST_PER_HR, RUN_COST_PER_HR, RUN_COST_PER_UNIT, BUR_PER_HR_SETUP, BUR_PER_HR_RUN, BUR_PER_UNIT_RUN, SERVICE_BASE_CHG, BUR_PERCENT_SETUP, BUR_PERCENT_RUN, " _
                                & "BUR_PER_OPERATION, EST_ATL_LAB_COST, EST_ATL_BUR_COST, EST_ATL_SER_COST, REM_ATL_LAB_COST, REM_ATL_BUR_COST, REM_ATL_SER_COST, ACT_ATL_LAB_COST, ACT_ATL_BUR_COST, " _
                                & "ACT_ATL_SER_COST, EST_TTL_MAT_COST, EST_TTL_LAB_COST, EST_TTL_BUR_COST, EST_TTL_SER_COST, REM_TTL_MAT_COST, REM_TTL_LAB_COST, REM_TTL_BUR_COST, REM_TTL_SER_COST, " _
                                & "ACT_TTL_MAT_COST, ACT_TTL_LAB_COST, ACT_TTL_BUR_COST, ACT_TTL_SER_COST, SPLIT_ADJUSTMENT, MILESTONE_ID, SCHEDULE_TYPE, MIN_SEGMENT_SIZE, PROTECT_COST, DRAWING_FILE, " _
                                & "DISPATCHED_QTY, SERVICE_MIN_CHG, VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_PART_ID, LAST_DISP_DATE, LAST_RECV_DATE, WAREHOUSE_ID, ALLOCATED_QTY, FULFILLED_QTY, " _
                                & "LEAST_MIN_MOVE_QTY, MAX_GAP_PREV_OP, APPLY_CALENDAR, MAX_DOWNTIME, ACCUM_DOWNTIME, RUN_QTY_PER_CYCLE, USER_1, USER_2, USER_3, USER_4, USER_5, USER_6, USER_7, USER_8, " _
                                & "USER_9, USER_10, UDF_LAYOUT_ID, NUM_MEM_TO_SCHED, SERVICE_BUFFER, MILESTONE_SUB_ID, POST_MILESTONE, PROJ_MILESTONE_OP, WBS_CODE, WBS_START_DATE, WBS_END_DATE, " _
                                & "WBS_DURATION, MILESTONE_SEQ_NO, PRD_INSP_PLAN_ID, SETUP_INSPECT_REQ, RUN_INSPECT_REQ, STATUS_EFF_DATE, PRED_SUB_ID, PRED_SEQ_NO, SITE_ID, SCHED_CAPACITY_USAGE)" _
                                & "SELECT WORKORDER_TYPE, WORKORDER_BASE_ID + 'F', WORKORDER_LOT_ID, WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, WORKORDER_SUB_ID, SEQUENCE_NO, RESOURCE_ID, SETUP_HRS, " _
                                & "RUN, RUN_TYPE, LOAD_SIZE_QTY, RUN_HRS, MOVE_HRS, TRANSIT_DAYS, SERVICE_ID, SCRAP_YIELD_PCT, SCRAP_YIELD_TYPE, FIXED_SCRAP_UNITS, MINIMUM_MOVE_QTY, CALC_START_QTY, " _
                                & "CALC_END_QTY, COMPLETED_QTY, DEVIATED_QTY, ACT_SETUP_HRS, ACT_RUN_HRS, 'R', SETUP_COMPLETED, SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE, NULL, OPERATION_TYPE, DRAWING_ID, DRAWING_REV_NO, " _
                                & "OVERRIDE_QTYS, BEGIN_TRACEABILITY, CAPACITY_USAGE_MAX, CAPACITY_USAGE_MIN, TEST_ID, SPC_QTY, NULL, NULL, NULL, ISDETERMINANT, " _
                                & "SETUP_COST_PER_HR, RUN_COST_PER_HR, RUN_COST_PER_UNIT, BUR_PER_HR_SETUP, BUR_PER_HR_RUN, BUR_PER_UNIT_RUN, SERVICE_BASE_CHG, BUR_PERCENT_SETUP, BUR_PERCENT_RUN, " _
                                & "BUR_PER_OPERATION, EST_ATL_LAB_COST, EST_ATL_BUR_COST, EST_ATL_SER_COST, REM_ATL_LAB_COST, REM_ATL_BUR_COST, REM_ATL_SER_COST, ACT_ATL_LAB_COST, ACT_ATL_BUR_COST, " _
                                & "ACT_ATL_SER_COST, EST_TTL_MAT_COST, EST_TTL_LAB_COST, EST_TTL_BUR_COST, EST_TTL_SER_COST, REM_TTL_MAT_COST, REM_TTL_LAB_COST, REM_TTL_BUR_COST, REM_TTL_SER_COST, " _
                                & "ACT_TTL_MAT_COST, ACT_TTL_LAB_COST, ACT_TTL_BUR_COST, ACT_TTL_SER_COST, SPLIT_ADJUSTMENT, MILESTONE_ID, SCHEDULE_TYPE, MIN_SEGMENT_SIZE, PROTECT_COST, DRAWING_FILE, " _
                                & "DISPATCHED_QTY, SERVICE_MIN_CHG, VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_PART_ID, LAST_DISP_DATE, LAST_RECV_DATE, WAREHOUSE_ID, ALLOCATED_QTY, FULFILLED_QTY, " _
                                & "LEAST_MIN_MOVE_QTY, MAX_GAP_PREV_OP, APPLY_CALENDAR, MAX_DOWNTIME, ACCUM_DOWNTIME, RUN_QTY_PER_CYCLE, USER_1, USER_2, USER_3, USER_4, USER_5, USER_6, USER_7, USER_8, " _
                                & "USER_9, USER_10, UDF_LAYOUT_ID, NUM_MEM_TO_SCHED, SERVICE_BUFFER, MILESTONE_SUB_ID, POST_MILESTONE, PROJ_MILESTONE_OP, WBS_CODE, WBS_START_DATE, WBS_END_DATE, " _
                                & "WBS_DURATION, MILESTONE_SEQ_NO, PRD_INSP_PLAN_ID, SETUP_INSPECT_REQ, RUN_INSPECT_REQ, STATUS_EFF_DATE, PRED_SUB_ID, PRED_SEQ_NO, SITE_ID, SCHED_CAPACITY_USAGE" _
                                & "FROM  MBUK.dbo.OPERATION db2 " _
                                & "WHERE  (db2.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = '" & rw.Cells(8).Value & "')")
                                CMDoperation.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error I get is {"Incorrect syntax near '.'."}

The SQL command is simply inserting data from a table in database A into a table in database B... Nothing complex.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If you formatted your SQL, you'd likely easily find the problem.

Comment: What's the resulting SQL query that this builds at runtime which ends up failing?

Comment: `" & rw.Cells(8).Value & "` ← Change that and use a `SqlParameter` instead. There are multiple benifits to using parameters including 1) prevent sql injection attacks, 2) query plan reuse 3) syntax errors if unescaped values are encountered like a `'` character. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204)

Comment: Actually, after formatting that mess, I can't see any syntax error. Maybe it's the value of `rw.Cells(8).Value`

Comment: Another suggestion would be to move your connection string to the config file instead of hard coding it all over the place. And PLEASE learn to use parameters before [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit. You won't like him very much.

Comment: Thanks for your comments all... I've taken them all on board, will use parameters going forward and I'll also look at the XML literals to format my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my 2 cents:
pay attention to VB concatenation, the end of the line is strictly attached to the following one, so in your code

```
 & "WBS_DURATION, MILESTONE_SEQ_NO, PRD_INSP_PLAN_ID, SETUP_INSPECT_REQ, RUN_INSPECT_REQ, STATUS_EFF_DATE, PRED_SUB_ID, PRED_SEQ_NO, SITE_ID, SCHED_CAPACITY_USAGE" _
 & "FROM  MBUK.dbo.OPERATION db2 " _
```

vb ends concatenating words in this way: **SCHED_CAPACITY_USAGE*FROM***

so add an extra space at the end of each line you concatenate.

Comment: [How to write readable SQL in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31714023/1115360) shows a way to avoid errors like the one that caused this problem.

Comment: That's it! I thought I'd checked that but as soon as I read your post I knew that's what it was... All sorted now, thank you.