# What's the data type of literals in SQL Server management studio or other clients?

Tags: sql-server, literals, sqldatatypes

In SSMS, if I have a query like:

```
select * from dbo.students where name = 'jim'
```

Or

```
select 1, 1000
```

What's the data type of `'jim'`, `1` and `1000`? They could be `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, `nchar`, `tinyint`, `smallint`, `int` or `bigint`. I want to know how to identify their types. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in information_schema.columns or sys.columns I can't remember which one.

Comment: I want to know the data type of the literals, not some table columns.

Comment: I have to ask, where are you going with this? The data type is driven by the data type of the column in the table. Not the literal.

Comment: Then use variant property. SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY

Comment: @R.Richards, what if no table involved like my second example?

Comment: SQL Server will use the set order until one fits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: Okay! Got it. Makes much more sense. I have always made assumptions about datatype literals. `1` -> `int`; `'string'` -> `varchar`.

Comment: @scsimon Data type precedence is about what happens when comparing two items of different types, not how literals are interpreted.

Comment: Some examples of different formats here and how to see the types http://stackoverflow.com/a/7428636/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith so you are saying the same precedence isn't used for interpretation? Then what precedence is?

Comment: @scsimon no it isn't used for interpretation. SQL variant is top so pretty much everything would be interpreted as that if that was the case. And the string `'123'` is a varchar literal despite that being near the bottom with lots of other stuff it could cast to above it. It determines what happens if you compare different types. So `varcharcolumn = N'foo'` means the column gets converted to nvarchar to match the literal.