# SQL Server Other Prefix Identifiers

Tags: sql-server

My question is somewhat related to :

[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

I understand the N prefix, but I am curious - are there more I can use? I can only find documentation for this one and for binary constants. I've tried googling in various ways but I have come up empty handed. If there are more I would like to know what they are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No other prefixes (except currency symbols). Some ways that datatype is inferred from literals are in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428538/curly-braces-in-t-sql/7428636#7428636

Comment: `money` via the literals £4.95 / $2.00 etc

Comment: Thank you very much this was helpful